# Cpanel PHP Update, problems with loading

Tags: php, cpanel

after my hosting provider updated their PHP in cpanel, my site cannot load its php files, someone else made these file and i am trying to detect what the problem might be, here is the output of executed php:

Warning: include(folder_include/config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 2

Warning: include(folder_include/config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 2

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'folder_include/config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php52/lib/php') in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 2

Warning: include(folder_include/class.database.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 3

Warning: include(folder_include/class.database.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 3

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'folder_include/class.database.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php52/lib/php') in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 3

Warning: include(folder_include/class.misc.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 4

Warning: include(folder_include/class.misc.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 4

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'folder_include/class.misc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php52/lib/php') in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 4

Warning: include(folder_include/class.website.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 5

Warning: include(folder_include/class.website.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 5

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'folder_include/class.website.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php52/lib/php') in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 5

Warning: include(folder_include/class.korpa.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 6

Warning: include(folder_include/class.korpa.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 6

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'folder_include/class.korpa.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php52/lib/php') in /home/website/public_html/v3/folder_include/classes.php on line 6

Regards

Comment: the warnings are self-explanatory.

Comment: I am not really into PHP that much i just maintain CMSs, can you tell me what could be done? Thanks for commend tho.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see these lines to know the problem, but probably the function syntax or name was changed.